# 3.3v current issues

Tags: relay, 3.3v

I am very new to the world of electronics and have run in to an issue with a relay. I have a Wemos chip that has GPIO pins. I measured 3v coming from a pin but it doesn't seem to trigger the 3v relay. My limited knowledge tells me this is a current issue. Is it possible to increase the current with an additional component?

I'd be greatful for any advice.

thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a schematic as well as the relay part number and/or a link to the relays datasheet?

Comment: Are you actually reading 3V on the relay?

Comment: What pin? What relay? You expect us to guess??

Comment: Are you driving the relay directly from the I/O pin? I'd almost bet that you can't drive it directly, and even if you could I would also guess you are missing the flyback protection.

Comment: srd-03vdc-sl-l is the relay. With the original hope of driving it from pin on the Wemos mini di.      D3 pin reading 3.2v on the Wemos

Comment: It takes a minimum of 120mA to drive that coil...

Comment: Yeah, I think you will need to drive it with a transistor controlled by your 3.3V pin output.

Comment: thanks you all for this great feedback!. Is there a generic transistor for this type of job? Without bogging myself down in all the variations! Thanks again

Comment: @Kyle - You could use an NPN BJT (2N3904 is a standard part) or N-channel MOSFET (2N7000 is a standard part).

Comment: @vofa thank you so much for that. It was sea of parts I was not sure of!

Comment: @Kyle - Edit your question to include the required information (don't make people hunt for it in the comment section). That way your question is more easily understood.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have my doubts that a 2N7000 N-MOSFET will work here. Looking at the 2N7000's data sheet, for VGS=3V, it looks to me like ID<100mA for VDS>0.5V. If you want to use an N-MOSFET to drive the relay's coil, you might try instead something like a Microchip Technology (formerly Supertex) TN0702N3-G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [srd-03vdc-sl-l relay datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/321/27115-Single-Relay-Board-Datasheet-709206.pdf), the 3-V version of coil needs 120 - 150 mA of current to operate. This coil is 25 Ohms only. No general-purpose microcontroller can output 120 mA at 3 V. It is likely that the measurement was done in some wrong way.

The Wemos board is based on [ESP-8266EX IC](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2471/0A-ESP8266__Datasheet__EN_v4.3.pdf), which has 12 mA load capability on GPIOS. From VIH (75% of Vcc) at nominal 12 mA it follows that the output stage has about 70 Ohm of internal resistance. Loading a 70-Ohm GPIO with 25 Ohms should result in maybe 1 V on the coil. This won't work. The design needs a transistor switch to operate this relay.